# Help with .htaccess RewriteRule. Need to take user from one URL to other

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting, mod-rewrite

I want users who type

```
http://www.example.com/word-of-the-day
```

to be taken to

```
http://www.example.com/index.php?page=word-of-the-day
```

But I want

```
http://www.example.com/word-of-the-day
```

to be shown in the URL for the user.

What should I do in my .htaccess? I tried but the regular expression
and the syntax of RewriteRule is way too complicated for me to
figure out how to do it.

Any help will be appreciated.

**Edit:**

Also, how can I say this in htaccess -

if they type `http://www.example.com/word-of-the-day`, take them to `http://www.example.com/index.php?page=word-of-the-day`

or if they type `http://www.example.com/something-else`, take them to `http://www.example.com/index.php?page=something-else`

or else, just take them to the URL they typed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteRule ^word-of-the-day$ index.php?page=word-of-the-day
```

Or more flexible

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?page=$1
```

Not tested, yet it sould work.

**To your edit:**

Just define those specific URLs manually:

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteRule ^word-of-the-day$ index.php?page=word-of-the-day
RewriteRule ^word-some-example$ index.php?page=some-example
RewriteRule ^some-other$ index.php?page=some-other
```

Comment: Please check out my edit. What if I want to specify three conditions like I said. Will your first piece of code work?

Comment: Its like, I have 2 - 3 specific URLS for which I need to rewrite the URL, but for the rest, I need to just leave it like that. Did you get my problem?

Comment: Yeah … a pretty common one. You'll have to specify them manually.

Comment: So, that will take care of those 3 specific URLs and won't touch if the URL is in any other format. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: what if, in order to make it more specific, I want to do the rewrite only if the string "word-of-the-day" exists in the REQUEST_URI part (and not in the QUERY_STRING part)? I tried with something similar to `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}   ^word-of-the-day$  RewriteRule index.php?page=word-of-the-day [L]` in my problem but it does not work. Any pointers? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The condition below checks that index.php is not being requested. If not apply the rule. This will work for any of the scenarios you listed above.

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}  ^!.*[index\.php].*$ [NC]    
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?page=$1 [L]
```

In response to your comment about only wanting to do this for a few specific pages, it would look like this(as an alternative to Nils edit):

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}  ^!.*[index\.php].*$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}   ^word-of-the-day$ [OR]  
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}   ^something-else$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}   ^even-something-else$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?page=$1 [L]
```

Comment: This RewriteRule will work for any URL in the format right? I do not want that. I want tit to be rewritten only for 2 - 3 URLs, but others I need to leave them alone.

Comment: if you want it specifically for only a few pages look at Nils first suggestions below, and copy that for each page you would like.